# Which side should the "hat" of unit vectors point to?

Tags: notation

*I'm not sure whether to post this here or on TeX.SE. If it belongs there, please move it.*

When working with unit vectors in physics class, we usually write them with an upside down hat, like this: $\check{\imath}\, \check{\jmath} \,\check{\rho}$. But when looking online, I usually found them written like this: $\hat{\imath}\, \hat{\jmath} \,\hat{\rho}$. Is there a correct way to do it, or is it just convention?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have never seen the upside-down hat, but I don't really think it matters so long as you mention it explicitly the first time you use it and you remain consistent afterwards. I'm very used to the upward hat - in my linear algebra classes, that's how I have taught it. And when I dabble in physics, it plays nicely with their concepts of measurables in quantum mechanics.